# Getting "cannot load such file -- devise (LoadError)" in terminal when using $ rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am new to rails and am having trouble with `devise` in a [tutorial](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-prelaunch-signup.html) I am working through.

When trying to test out the application (which was working fine earlier) and launching `$ rails s`, I get the below stack trace:

```
Patricks-MacBook-Air:rails-prelaunch-signup patrickvihtelic$ rails s
/Users/patrickvihtelic/code/rails-prelaunch-signup/config/application.rb:13:in `require': cannot load such file -- devise (LoadError)
    from /Users/patrickvihtelic/code/rails-prelaunch-signup/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/patrickvihtelic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/patrickvihtelic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/patrickvihtelic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/patrickvihtelic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails326/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any hints or suggestions would much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: What devise version are you using?

Comment: Did you "bundle install" devise?